# Confluence is not showing styles when running behind apache

Tags: css, file, missing-data, confluence

I'm running a jira and a confluence behind an apache proxy.

My problem is, that confluence has no css stylesheets.

He tries to load from http://foo.bar/wiki/foo.css which results in a 404. If I change foo.bar to the correct Ip address and port (192.168.1.150:8090), it works like a charm.

my proxy conf (I'm not familiar with mod_proxy)

```
<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyRequests           Off
ProxyPreserveHost       On
ProxyPass               /jenkins  http://localhost:8081/jenkins/
ProxyPassReverse        /jenkins  http://localhost:8081/jenkins/
ProxyPass               /wiki     http://localhost:8090/wiki/
ProxyPassReverse        /wiki     http://localhost:8090/wiki/
ProxyPass               /         http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse        /         http://localhost:8080/

<Location /wiki>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Location>
```

The entries for jira and jenkins are working like a charm:

```
http://foo.bar --> Jira
http://foo.bar/jenkins --> jenkins
http://foo.bar/wiki --> Confluence with no styles and images
```

Pls help :'(

Comment: What's in the <Context> and <Connector> of your $CONFLUENCE_HOME/conf/server.xml? Does the 404 page tell you what server is returning the error? (ie. is it Httpd or Tomcat?) Does everything except CSS otherwise seem to load? When you say that it works like a charm when you "change to the correct IP address and port (192.168.1.150:8090)", did you mean "http://192.168.1.150:8090/wiki"?

Comment: "192.168.1.150:8090/wiki" Exactly. I mean this. I've changed <Context> Path to /wiki and nothing else.

Comment: You also need to [add the proxyName and proxyPort stuff to the Connector](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Using+Apache+with+mod_proxy), although I don't think that's the direct cause for this problem. Does the 404 page tell you whether it is Tomcat or Httpd that is returning the error? And does everything except CSS otherwise seem to load? And can you provide the exact URL of one of the CSS files that is returning 404?

Comment: You could be right with proxyName and proxyPort stuff. I'll try this, thank you.

Comment: I added proxyName and proxyPort, but same problem. The 404 page tells me, that apache is returning the 404 (Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1). 

Here is one url of one css file: http://internal.dev/wiki/s/79430b2493f4e2f35052901b3f1210a0/de_DE/5501/a39771cd4bb7ab00a226a7ea8d6dd65e64226a7f.1/11/_/download/superbatch/css/batch.css

If I change "internal.dev" to "192.168.1.150:8090", the css file can be loaded.

Comment: I removed the last / at "http://localhost:8090/wiki/" and now its working. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the last / at "localhost:8090/wiki/"; and now its working. Thanks for your help

Comment: This answer pretty much sums up what life of a developer looks like.